# Grok and regex on an URL

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

Given the following as an input:

```
https://api.example.net:443/v1/domain/action
https://api.exmaple.net:443/v2/domain/action?tag=test
https://api.example.net:443/v3/domain/action/test
```

What Grok regular expression can break all of the above into:

```
{
  "request_endpoint": [
    [
      "https://api.example.net:443"
    ]
  ],
  "request_version": [
    [
      "v3"
    ]
  ],
  "request_domain": [
    [
      "domain"
    ]
  ],
  "request_api": [
    [
      "action"
    ]
  ]
}
```

This is the closest I was able to get, but there's an `/n` if the first example is passed:

```
/(?<request_endpoint>[^/]+)+/(?<request_version>[^/]+)+/(?<request_domain>[^/]+)/(?<request_api>[^/!\?]+)
```

I was testing with https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves it, I was getting the newline character because my test string had that :(

`/(?<request_endpoint>[^/]+)+/(?<request_version>[^/]+)+/(?<request_domain>[^/]+)/(?<request_api>[^/!\?]+)`